# convert object to json in vb .net or c#.net

Tags: json, vb.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing restful web service using vb.net web api 2, I'm trying to pass parameters from the body to execute my stored procedure,

```
{
    "id": "2016", 
    "Type":"1", 
    "Year": "1"
}
```

here is the data I'm passing from the body, and here is error

> { "message": "System.InvalidCastException: Conversion from type
>   'JObject' to type 'String' is not valid.\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString(Object
>   Value)\r\n   at
>   WebApplication7.Controllers.SubjectsController.getSubjects(Object
>   data) in C:\Users\Junaida\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication7\WebApplication7\Controllers\SubjectsController.vb:line
>   30" }

my vb code :

```
    <HttpPost>
    Function getSubjects(<FromBody> ByVal data As Object) As IHttpActionResult
        Try
            Using entities As IAPD_DBEntities = New IAPD_DBEntities()

                Dim year, type, id As String
                Dim dictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data) 'As  Dictionary(Of String, String)


                Dim startno As Integer = 0
                If year = 1 Then
                    startno = 0
                ElseIf year = 2 And type = 1 Then
                    startno = 366
                ElseIf year = 2 And type = 3 Then
                    startno = 52
                ElseIf year = 2 And type = 2 Then
                    startno = 13
                End If

                dictionary.Add("id", id)
                dictionary.Add("Type", type)
                dictionary.Add("Year", year)

                Return Ok(entities.SP_Messages_GetinfoArchive_ByID(startno, id, type, year).ToList)
            End Using
        Catch e As Exception
            Return BadRequest(e.ToString)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a class with properties matching the fields of the incoming JSON structure, and then MVC Web API will do the parsing for you! No need to deserialize yourself.

Example class:

```
Public Class SubjectParams
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property year As String
End Class
```

And then use it like this:

```
<HttpPost>
Function getSubjects(<FromBody> ByVal data As SubjectParams) As IHttpActionResult
```

You can then use `data.id`, `data.type` etc.

If you need the properties to be of other types, just make it so (esp. `Integer` seems to make sense for at least some of the properties).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1220550/peter-b thank you, done it already i passed parameter of type JObject and created three variables of type JValue and give them the value of data.gettoken("id"), and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I think your `data` object is already a `JObject` and `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` is expecting a string.  You should be able to access its properties without deserializing it, like this:

```
dictionary.add("id", data("id").ToString())
dictionary.add("Type", data("Type").ToString())
dictionary.add("Year", data("Year").ToString())
```

It should work.